# My StopwatchApp only counts down for a second, then stops working. What is the problem? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, dom

I am currently working on a stopwatch app, where you can set your values (in minutes, seconds, and hours) and it would count down until it reaches zero. The problem is that it would only go down for a single second then stop working entirely. What is the problem here?

```js
let hours = document.getElementById('hours')
let mins = document.getElementById('minutes')
let secs = document.getElementById('seconds')
let submit = document.getElementById('submit')
let time = document.getElementById('time')
let runningProgramKey = null;

submit.addEventListener('click', startTimer)

function startTimer() {
  //window.variable is not a flaw, I am using it to define a global variable inside the function
  window.hoursX = Math.abs(parseInt(hours.value)) || 0;
  window.minsX = Math.abs(parseInt(mins.value)) || 0
  window.secsX = Math.abs(parseInt(secs.value)) || 0
  window.timeX = `${hoursX}:${minsX}:${secsX}`
  time.textContent = timeX;
  runTime();
}

function runTime() {
  if (runningProgramKey) clearInterval(runningProgramKey);
   runningProgramKey = setInterval(() => {
    time.textContent = updateTime(hoursX,minsX,secsX);
  },1000)
}

function updateTime(hours,minutes,seconds) {
  //I know I can use ternary operators however I am not (for a reason)
  if (seconds - 1 > 0) {
    seconds--;
    if (minutes >= 1 && seconds === 0) {
      minutes--;
    }
  }
  return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

function clearTime() {

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>StopwatchApp</title>
    <script defer src='script.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input id='hours' type='text' placeholder="Hours">
      <input id='minutes' type='text' placeholder="Minutes">
      <input id='seconds' type='text' placeholder="Seconds">
      <input id='submit' type='button' value='Go'>
    </div>
    <h1 id='time'>HH:MM:SS</h1>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Just for clarification and to save people's time, the error is not `if (runningProgramKey) clearInterval(runningProgramKey);` I know because I did multiple things, even commenting that line out and the error still proceeds.

To see a visualization of what happens press `run snippet` which should be under my code. It gives you another clear idea on what is the problem.

My code is not finished, therefore some functionality would be questioning, such as the seconds stopping at 0. This isn't a complete script, and I came to get help on my error so that I can continue working on the project.What I don't like is the fact that people in the comments section are not simply acknowledging this, and complaining about the matter. Next time please read to identify what the problem actually is before attempting to post rants in the comment section. I'm not "ranting" on the people who 'want to help' I am "ranting" on the people who halfly read the question and want to try and insult me for the code, even them knowing that the code is not complete.

Comment: I updated my question to include both the html and javascript, and countering the common beliefs on the code

Comment: You should pay attention to the callback you provided to `setInterval`. Every time, it is getting called with the same values, not with updated ones.

Comment: `minutes--;` can't be reached, since if `seconds -1 > 0`, 'seconds--` can't be 0

Comment: And @Turo of course seconds cant be 0. That's not the problem. If I set seconds to something like 55, it would go to 54 then stop

Comment: so you are happy with dead code?

Comment: *"That's not the problem"*: it would be wise to think a bit more before waving the analysis you get here. Turo is of course right. NB: there are multiple problems with your code

Comment: @Turo What? Of course the code is dead I'm not even finished with the stopwatch yet. I went to stack overflow to get this error fixed, because I am unable to continue without it. Anyways, I found my solution. Thanks for your concern

Comment: @trincot Those 'problems' are because I am not finished. So of course it would stop at 0, and do the other behavior. There aren't problems with the script itself, it is just the fact that I am not finished with the code. I went to stack overflow to get help with this bug so that I can continue working on the project. What he mentioned was what I programmed so far and not a bug. It isn't the error I am talking about if you read the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you pass the number as a parameter to a function a copy of parameter is created in stack,if you change the variable ,just its copy will change and the original variable won't change.
you should use global variable.

```
function updateTime() {
  //I know I can use ternary operators however I am not (for a reason)
  if (secsX- 1 > 0) {
    secsX--;
    if (minsX>= 1 && secsX=== 0) {
      minsX--;
    }
  }
  return `${hoursX}:${minsX}:${secsX}`;
}
```